# Issue loading external JSON with SurveyJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, surveyjs

I have the following [Codepen](https://codepen.io/flowtrader/pen/oQoNGZ) working with a very simple example of SurveyJS.  It uses the following JSON:

```
var json = {
    "questions": [{
            "type": "text",
            "title": "Test question 1",
            "name": "Test question"
        },
        {
            "type": "comment",
            "title": "Test question 2",
            "name": "Test question 2"
        },

    ]
}
```

When I try to use a [remote](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/flowtrader2016/cdb63289fc3b4c81df9186e339233ffa/raw/1ee651735f501d5288082a0f3147ea48dc07911c/surverytest.json) file for the JSON the [new Codepen](https://codepen.io/flowtrader/pen/oQoNae) is not working.

I tried requesting the JSON as follows:

```
var giturl = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/flowtrader2016/cdb63289fc3b4c81df9186e339233ffa/raw/1ee651735f501d5288082a0f3147ea48dc07911c/surverytest.json"

$.getJSON( giturl, function (data) {
      var json = data
});
```

I'm just starting to learn a bit of Javascript so appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've slightly modified your codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmxGzW

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
  var giturl = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tsv2013/43c1e94c6e663e242d772ba9f79e8c2f/raw/1a9378226b633459037c798cf44354b631f9a9c9/surverytest.json";

    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: giturl,
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log("received: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        var survey = new Survey.Model(JSON.parse(data));

        survey
            .onComplete
            .add(function (result) {
                document
                    .querySelector('#surveyResult')
                    .innerHTML = "result: " + JSON.stringify(result.data);
            });

        $("#surveyElement").Survey({model: survey});

      }
    });

    console.log("sent");
});
```

And your survey JSON has an error - an extra comma

#### By the way - any example on https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/ can be opened in pluker via single mouse click on the `Edit in Plunker` button